# What is the proper way of referencing a field in a SSRS dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I am using SSRS 2014 SP1 x64 and VS2013 Update 5.

I have the following expressions to attempt to calculate ageing on a statement report.

```
=SUM(IIF(DateDiff("d", (Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), Now())<=0, (Fields!LineAmount.Value, "Invoice"), 0))
=SUM(IIF(DateDiff("d", (Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=1 and DateDiff("d", (Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"),Now())<=30, (Fields!LineAmount.Value, "Invoice"), 0))
=SUM(IIF(DateDiff("d", (Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=31 and DateDiff("d", (Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), Now())<=60, (Fields!LineAmount.Value, "Invoice"), 0))
=SUM(IIF(DateDiff("d", (Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=61 and DateDiff("d", (Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), Now())<=90, (Fields!LineAmount.Value, "Invoice"), 0))
=SUM(IIF(DateDiff("d", (Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=91, (Fields!LineAmount.Value, "Invoice"), 0))
```

Now when I try to add `First` to the field selector I get an error stating `... uses a First, Last or Previous aggregate in an outer aggregate.`

How exactly do I reference this field from the Invoice dataset (there are at least two datasets)?

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee210531(v=sql.120).aspx) function to reference a field from a second dataset

Comment: How does the `Lookup` function help to return the value of a single Field? Wouldn't the `RunningValue(expression, function, scope)` be a better aggregate function? That way I can specify the scope and not have to compare values.

Comment: As you mentioned there are multi datasets in your report. I guess what you want is to put the field from Invoice dataset into a tablix/matrix which has another dataset embedded. Lookup function is like a SQL join function to link two datasets. Other than Lookup function and LookupSet function, most RS functions work in one dataset only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work:

```
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), Now())<=0, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=1 and DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"),Now())<=30, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=31 and DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"),Now())<=60, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=61 and DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"),Now())<=90, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=91, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
```